# OrientDB: how to connect to multiple remote hosts in a distributed cluster?

Tags: distributed, orientdb

Pretend I have 3 OrientDB hosts running in distributed mode together, at these addresses:

- 192.168.10.4
- 192.168.10.5
- 192.168.10.6

Using the Java client, the typical way to fetch a reference to the database is to do this:

```
 this.graphFactory = new OrientGraphFactory(
            "remote:[host]/[database]",
            "username",
            "password")
            .setupPool([...], [...]);
```

In the connection string argument, how can I indicate that there are multiple hosts? My first instinct is to manually set up a TCP load balancer (i.e. HAProxy) on a separate IP and have it distribute it between my 3 hosts.

Is there a way to tell the API that there are multiple IPs to choose from, or should I set up a load balancer in front of my instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use all those addresses separated by a semicolon:

```
remote:192.168.10.4/db;remote:192.168.10.5/db;remote:192.168.10.6/db
```

OrientDB will try connecting to the first, but if it's unreachable, it will try the others in sequence.

Comment: OK, that works, but in theory, this means my first server will handle a lot more traffic than the other 2, correct?

Comment: Correct. However, in v2.2 you have load balancing at client side.

Comment: what if we have different passwords and user names for the servers?

Comment: you will have to use same username password across all your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The above  way of connecting to database didn't work for me.

I tried remote:host1/host2/host3/{databsename}

example: remote:192.168.10.4;192.168.10.5;192.168.10.6/db

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

*2019-07-01 ShangHai*

For **v3.0.x**, multi nodes connection looks like this:

```
remote:{ip_1},{ip_2},{ip_3}/{database_name}
```

OrientDB JavaApi Demo:

```java
String url = "remote:{ip_1},{ip_2},{ip_3}/{database_name}";
String username = "username";
String password = "password";

// FIXME: I'm not sure the pool configuration is suit for you, may be you can use the default config.

OrientDBConfigBuilder poolCfg = OrientDBConfig.builder();
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MIN, 1);
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MAX, 100);
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.CLIENT_CONNECTION_STRATEGY, OStorageRemote.CONNECTION_STRATEGY.ROUND_ROBIN_CONNECT);

ODatabasePool pool = new ODatabasePool(url, userName, password, poolCfg.build());
ODatabaseSession session = pool.acquire();
session.begin();
....
```

---

> OrientDB source code

```java
  public OrientDB(String url, String serverUser, String serverPassword, OrientDBConfig configuration) {
    int pos;
    String what;
    if ((pos = url.indexOf(':')) > 0) {
      what = url.substring(0, pos);
    } else {
      what = url;
    }
    if ("embedded".equals(what) || "memory".equals(what) || "plocal".equals(what))
      internal = OrientDBInternal.embedded(url.substring(url.indexOf(':') + 1), configuration);

=========================== HERE =========================
    else if ("remote".equals(what))
      internal = OrientDBInternal.remote(url.substring(url.indexOf(':') + 1).split(","), configuration);
=========================== HERE =========================

    else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong url:`" + url + "`");

    this.serverUser = serverUser;
    this.serverPassword = serverPassword;
  }
```